Gitlab - import CSV and link new issue to existing issues
I'm uploading issues in Gitlab from a CSV file.
Every row representa a Test Case.
I would like to link every new imported "Test Case" issue to its "Requirement"/"User Story" issue.
I know I can use quick actions inside issues description for executing "adjustments" during import.
However, quick action for linking needs 2 issue ids:
 /relate #issue1 #issue2

The problem here is that I only know the issue id for the Requirement (already created in Gitlab). The other issue id will be created only after import.
Is it possible in Gitlab?

I found that #issue2 is optional.
If during upload you specify just #issue1 like this:
/relate #123

this will link the newly created issue to issue #123.
Following a working csv example:
title,description
An issue title,"Issue description

/relate #123"

